# Verenti Technique 2015 - Crankset upgrade

Tags: shimano

My verenti road bike (Wiggle own brand) has an unbranded crankset which I am thinking of upgrading to a Shimano 105. Does anyone know if I will need to change the bottom bracket as well ?

Comment: A photo would help - ideally you need to find out what the crank to bottom bracket axle interface is.  I've checked wiggle's website and they show Claris<Sora<Tiagra groupsets in road bikes for this year but no further info.    How old is it?

Comment: Another thought - if you've done enough mileage on it, a new cartridge bottom bracket is money well spent.   Especially if it has cup and cone bearings originally.

Answer (score 2):

It being an "unbranded crankset", I don't think anyone here could tell you that.  May be a good idea to change it anyways, as usually complete bikes are specced with the cheapest compatible BB, and as that is one of the prime spinning parts of your bike, upgrading it even a little usually goes a long way.